# Deserializing struct with TreatValueAsRefType in ServiceStack.Text

Tags: deserialization, servicestack-text

Migrating to ServiceStack I faced serialization issue in (de)serializing struct. On struct I can override ToString() and add static Parse() method but then the output of serialization is string, which is **escaped** into JSON.

I would prefer the same serialization as for class - properties of struct being serialized as JSON properties, using DataContract attributes. I found setting JsConfig.TreatValueAsRefType, which works for serialization but not for deserialization - during Deserialization I'm getting default (empty) values in MyStruct.
As I briefly looked into source files it seems to me the setting is not used for deserialization at all. Currently I only can use workaround to provide Parse() method, where I can parse the json and create the object.

Am I misusing TreatValueAsRefType for struct or is it just not yet finished feature?